# Definition of Dirichlet energy

Tags: integration, minimal-surfaces

I don't understand definition of [Dirichlet energy](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energ%C3%ADa_de_Dirichlet)

$$ E[u]:=\frac{1}{2} \int_\Omega \Vert \nabla u  \Vert^2 $$
for $u:\Omega \to \mathbb R^n$ with $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$.
Let's consider for example $u: \Omega \to \mathbb R^2$. What would

$$ \Vert \nabla u \Vert^2 $$
mean? Can we say it's determinant of Jacobi Matrix of $u$ or rather quadratic sum of all components of it?

Edit: for the people wondering  Dirichlet energy in general is defined as:

$$E[u]:=\frac{1}{2} \int_\Omega trace(du^t\cdot du)$$

Comment: $$||\nabla u||^2=\nabla u\cdot\nabla u$$

Comment: @MarkViola I'm only familiar with $\nabla u$ as gradient of function $u$ from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R $, but according to definition above $u$ can be vector valued, in that case $\nabla u$ does not make sense to me. Is it some sort of generalisation? Thanks!

Comment: It might be a typo in the Spanish Wikipedia page you linked, since in the [English page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_energy) it has $u:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\nabla  u$ is a vector.

Comment: @angryavian, I thought so aswell, but in other notes it is defined is similiar way, see [Def 2.4  page 5](http://www.mit.edu/~cmad/Papers/MinSurfNotes.pdf)